# Relationships between StackExchange.Redis and SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-core, stackexchange.redis

Recently, I decided to use Redis for memory cache because it's faster and it's not a good idea to create additional tables just because of one specific strategy of mine.

I have two classes that have a relationship between each other and `BotSession`, respectively, has a relationship with another class from MSSQL.

These relationships are vital. Is this possible? If not what would you recommend me? I decided to use the cache because it fetches faster.

I have to store temporary class objects in the memory cache.

```
builder.Entity<BotSession>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(bs => bs.Bot)
        .WithMany(b => b.BotSessions)
        .HasForeignKey(bs => bs.BotId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    // Unique key
    entity.HasIndex(bs => new { bs.TrendType, bs.BotId })
        .IsUnique();
});

builder.Entity<Aggregation>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(a => a.BotSession)
        .WithMany(bs => bs.Aggregations)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.BotSessionId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    // Unique key
    entity.HasIndex(a => new { a.Type, a.BotSessionId })
        .IsUnique();
});
```

```
public class Aggregation
{
    public Aggregation()
    {
    }

    public Aggregation(AggregationType type, BinanceKline kline, int botSessionId)
    {
        Type = type;
        OpenTime = kline.OpenTime;
        CloseTime = kline.CloseTime;
        Open = kline.Open;
        High = kline.High;
        Low = kline.Low;
        Close = kline.Close;
        Volume = kline.Volume;
        BotSessionId = botSessionId;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OpenTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime CloseTime { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,8)")]
    public decimal Open { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,8)")]
    public decimal High { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,8)")]
    public decimal Low { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,8)")]
    public decimal Close { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,8)")]
    public decimal Volume { get; set; }

    public AggregationType Type { get; set; }

    public int BotSessionId { get; set; }
    public BotSession BotSession { get; set; }
}

public class BotSession
{
    public BotSession()
    {
    }

    public BotSession(TrendType trendType, int botId)
    {
        TrendType = trendType;
        CanTrade = false;
        StopLossValue = null;
        BotId = botId;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TrendType TrendType { get; set; }
    public bool CanTrade { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,8)")]
    public decimal? StopLossValue { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,8)")]
    public decimal? NTimes { get; set; }

    public int BotId { get; set; }
    public Bot Bot { get; set; }

    public List<Aggregation> Aggregations { get; set; }

    public bool IsUptrendSession()
        => TrendType == TrendType.Uptrend;
}
```

```
public static class CacheExtensions
{
    public static async Task<T> SetAsync<T>(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, T item)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);

        await cache.SetStringAsync(key, json);

        return await cache.GetAsync<T>(key);
    }

    public static async Task<T> SetAsync<T>(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, T item, int expirationInHours)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);

        await cache.SetStringAsync(key, json, new DistributedCacheEntryOptions
        {
            AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(expirationInHours)
        });

        return await cache.GetAsync<T>(key);
    }

    public static async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(this IDistributedCache cache, string key)
    {
        var json = await cache.GetStringAsync(key);

        if (json == null)
            return default;

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
}

// usage
var asd = await _cache.GetAsync<List<BotSession>>("Hey");
await _cache.SetAsync("Hey", sessions);
await _cache.RemoveAsync("Hey");
```

Comment: Any other ideas to achieve that, are also welcome

Comment: What are you actually asking?

Comment: Currently, I have those classes: `BotSession` and `Aggregation` in MSSQL. I want to move them in Redis but I don't know how to keep the relationship between them.

Comment: Have someone used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/memory-optimized-tables?

Comment: Update: I tried `IsMemoryOptimized()` in SQL Server but it doesn't seem to work with Cascade Delete/SetNull, not even with relationships between NoSQL and SQL database.

Comment: Redis is (and most in-memory/NoSQL databases are) designed specifically to **not** be relational in order to achieve high performance. If you require relational integrity of your stored data then you need to use a database that supports such. You should also remember that Redis is not a persistent store but an in-memory one, so any data stored in it is lost when the Redis service is restarted. In short: there are tradeoffs to using NoSQL DBs versus standard relational ones, you cannot just expect to swap one for the other without significant effort.